# Passing a method as an argument

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a method `SaveChanges<T>(T object)` that is frequently called throughout my code, except depending on the action calling the method, there would be a different method called from within SaveChanges.  Something like this...

```
protected void SaveChanges<T>(T mlaObject, SomeFunction(arg))
    where T : WebObject
{
    try { this._db.SaveChanges(); }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        SomeFunction(arg);
    }
}
```

Usage Examples:

```
SaveChanges<MlaArticle>(article, article.Authors.Remove(person)) //person is an object of type MlaPerson
//OR
SaveChanges<MlaArticle>(article, article.RelatedTags.Remove(tag)) //tag is an object of type Tag
//OR
SaveChanges<MlaArticle>(article, article.RelatedWebObjects.Remove(location)) //location is an object of type MlaLocation
```

I've read up on delegate methods but I'm a little confused as to how to implement this with my requirements or if my requirements warrant use for delegates at all.

EDIT: Also, would it be possible to pass multiple Actions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
protected void SaveChanges<T>(T mlaObject, Action<T> rollback)
    where T : WebObject
{
    try { this._db.SaveChanges(); }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        rollback(mlaObject);
    }
}
```

Called like:

```
this.SaveChanges(myObj, x => article.Authors.Remove(x));
```

Now, from a second read of your question, I don't see a point in passing the `mlaObject` as it is never used.

```
// this.SaveChanges(
//     () => article.Authors.Remove(author),
//     () => article.RelatedTags.Remove(tag));
protected void SaveChanges(params Action[] rollbacks)
{
    try { this._db.SaveChanges(); }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        foreach (var rollback in rollbacks) rollback();
    }
}

// Overload to support rollback with an argument
// this.SaveChanges(
//     author,
//     article.Authors.Remove,
//     authorCache.Remove);
protected void SaveChanges<T>(T arg, params Action<T>[] rollbacks)
{
    try { this._db.SaveChanges(); }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        foreach (var rollback in rollbacks) rollback(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add the arg parameter.

Comment: I like this, very straight forward.  Would it be possible to send multiple Actions?

Comment: Sure, you could take an IEnumerable<Action<T>> or your Action<T> itself could specify any number of things to call, like x => { doA(x); doB(x); doC(x); }

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: thanks, I intuited it to be `mlaObject`. But that may not be the case on a second read.

Comment: @bflemi3: Added support for multiple actions, removed the unused usage of `mlaObject`.

Comment: thanks sixlettervariables. this hits the nail on the head. this is perfect. I really appreciate you taking the time to reread.

Comment: Be warned, this is a anti-pattern in general! Your rollback code would never get executed if your code fails before you enter the SaveChanges method! you need to have the rollback in a catch around the entire transaction which would make it redundant in SaveChanges.

Comment: @sixlettervariables could you explain the significance of () in the lambda expression `() => article.Authors.Remove(author)`

Comment: @bflemi3: Certainly, shorthand for *no arguments*. Sorta like `delegate() { ... }`.

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE** I was a little unclear from your question if the arg passed in is being used anywhere else in the method, it doesn't look like it is, so you can just take an `Action` and use a lambda to specify the delegate to call with the captured argument:

```
protected void SaveChanges<T, TArg>(T mlaObject, TArg arg, Action undoFunction)
    where T : WebObject
{
    try { this._db.SaveChanges(); }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        undoFunction();
    }
}
```

To which you can pass:

```
SaveChanges(article, () => article.Authors.Remove(person));
```

Or if it's the myObj itself, in which case (as sixlettervariables already answered) you can just pass it back in a delegate as per his code.

Or, whether the arg is different from mlaObject and you want to also do other things on it in the code, in which case you could do:

```
protected void SaveChanges<T, TArg>(T mlaObject, TArg arg, Action undoFunction)
    where T : WebObject
{
    try { this._db.SaveChanges(); }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        undoFunction(arg);
    }
}
```

And then have:

```
SaveChanges(article, person, article.Authors.Remove);
```

Comment: I've have hope that i will newer have to work with such code without source or documentation ;-).

Comment: Well, ideally you'd have some good /// comments at least on it.  Action/Func delegates quickly become second nature especially when you start playing with LINQ.

Comment: This code really isn't that bad at all.  It might use something more complex than you need for a simple Notepad application, but real-world problems will use many features of the language.  This is very neat and self-explanatory.  Have you taken a look through some C or C++ code recently Vash?

Comment: My only question with this code is what is the utility of `T mlaObject` given it goes unused. Might not be a question for @JamesMichaelHare, but certainly is for the OP :)

Comment: Very good question, if it's unused then it's dropable of course, otherwise I had assumed there would be some usage in it leading up to the this._db.SaveChanges().

Comment: I'm refactoring my code, so orginally the method would attempt to savechanges via dbContext.savechanges() and then catch any validationErrors and remove the object from the dbset as well as remove two other associations in classes used to map relationships.

Comment: I'm going to override SaveChanges so that it accepts `IEnumerable<Action<>>` (as suggested by James Michael Hare) and see if I can't get that to work

Comment: Sounds like a good plan feel free to ask if there's any further questions.

Comment: @bflemi3: another route is `params Action<T>[] actions`, which'll make it cleaner looking in places. You could have that method call your `IEnumerable<Action<T>>` overload as well.

Answer (score 5):

```
protected void SaveChanges<T,U>(T mlaObject, Action<U> action, U arg)
    where T : WebObject
{
    try { this._db.SaveChanges(); }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        action(arg);
    }
}
```

Hope I understood the question correctly...

Comment: yep you got it correct.  would it be possible to send multiple Actions?

Answer (score 4):

Your `SaveChanges` method would look something like:

```
protected void SaveChanges<T,TArg>(T mlaObject, TArg arg, Action<T,TArg> someFunction)
    where T : WebObject
{
   ...
}
```

Called like:

```
SaveChanges<MlaArticle,Person>(article,person, (article,person) =>  article.Authors.Remove(person))
```

Comment: You'll have to supply the type of both generic arguments if you supply one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void SaveChanges<T>(T mlaObject, Action<T> functionToCall)
{
    try { this._db.SaveChanges(); }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        functionToCall(mlaObject);
    } 
}
```

Call like this:

```
SaveChanges(actualArticle, article => article.Authors.Remove(person));
```

I left out the WebObject bit as it was not used in the function at all.

Answer (score 0):

> if my requirements warrant use for delegates at all.

If you want the `SaveChanges` method to perform some function you have two options

- have it perform the function directly (code inside the method, or call some second method from inside the method); or
- provide the function to the `SaveChanges` method as a delegate.

When to use each of these is a design choice that is up to you and will depend on the scenario, the overall solution and your preference.

Benefits of the first

- Able to see every possible outcome of the `SaveChanges` method in one place
- Less confusing for someone who doesn't know how delegates work

Benefits of the second

- Able to exclude every possible function from the `SaveChanges` method (it doesn't require an enormous `case` or `if else if else if`)
- The functions that are passed to the `SaveChanges` method can be above it in the call stack, it doesn't need to know what they are or how they work, they can do things it doesn't understand, and they can be reused - called elsewhere or used as delegates in other functions.

I think the first point is the main one here. If you are only handling a couple of scenarios then it's okay to have a an `if else if else if`, but if you get more than a handful of options and prefer a more generic `SaveChanges` method then psdd that delegate.